# Setting up HTTP+HTTPs and TCP ports on a LoadBalancer (Want to forward GitLab SSH and Web)

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

The setup I want is rather simple. I am hosting gitlab inside a kubernetes cluster and the ingress for it is defined as:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: gitlab-public
  namespace: gitlab
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: git-public
spec:
  tls:
    - secretName: gitlab-cert
  backend:
    serviceName: gitlab
    servicePort: 80
```

This sets up everything for me - SSL termination is enabled, it uses my letsencrypt certificates. The problem is that (clearly) SSH is not working for the repository. The ports for 22 are exposed by the pods and I have verified it:

[image: Both SSH and HTTP ports are forwarded]

However, it looks like Ingress does not support a unified L4+L7 specification. A few other options I have considered so far:

1. Create another load balancer which only forwards 22 -> 22 as a TCP (or an L4 ingress) balancer. The problem is that multiple load balancers cannot share the same static IP.. which of course makes sense.
2. Basically do the previous thing, but get a new DNS and static IP, probably call it `ssh.git.mycompany.com` and use it to forward SSH traffic. The huge problem is that there are a lot of developers using this right now and they will have to change their `.git/config` files and it is going to be extremely disruptive (not in a Silicon Valley way).
3. Setup an L4 balancer (outside of any k8s config) and let it handle the SSL and setup three ports to be forwarded to 80 and 22. This is the most confusing step possible.. because I have no idea what the Google LoadBalancer is trying to do. I am not able to map frontends to backends, or even select my own port. Apparently, it has to be from a list of pre-defined ports, which is pretty dumb I guess? In contrast, we are currently hosted on AWS and this is how the load balancer looks:

[image]

What is the best way to get around this?

EDIT: Modifying the title since the answer is a bit GitLab specific so might help people looking for the exact problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I am not entirely sure if this works as an answer, because while it achieves everything we wanted to do; it does not support SSL termination for the load balancer.

So the basic compromise is this:

1. Make GitLab serve SSL connections with the bundled nginx controller. [NGINX Settings for GitLab](https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/nginx.html#manually-configuring-https)
2. Setup GitLab to forward HTTP -> HTTPs, standard stuff. Documentation covers most of it.
3. When letting the LoadBalancer handle SSL, you just had to point to a secret and that would work (it happens to be in a specific format with keys `tls.crt` and `tls.key`, both in pem format). You can carry over the same structure by mounting these two keys as a file and then changing the nginx settings (`ssl_certificate` and `ssl_certificate_key`):

In your volumes section:

volumes:
     - name: gitlab-cert
       secret:
       secretName: 
         items:
           - key: tls.key
             path: git.mycompany.com.key
           - key: tls.crt
             path: git.mycompany.com.crt

And mount it, in whichever location you want:

volumeMounts:
     - name: gitlab-certs
       mountPath: /etc/gitlab/ssl/

In the above case, this would make your `gitlab.rb` look like:

```
nginx['ssl_certificate'] = "/etc/gitlab/ssl/git.mycompany.com.crt"
nginx['ssl_certificate_key'] = "/etc/gitlab/ssl/git.mycompany.com.key"
```

In case your domain on which you are hosting is actually `git.mycompany.com`, then you can skip this step because the location showed above is what it defaults to.

And then finally instead of using an Ingress, just expose your deployment:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: gitlab
  namespace: gitlab
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  loadBalancerIP: <your-static-ip>
  ports:
    - port: 80
      name: http
      targetPort: 80
      protocol: TCP
    - port: 443
      name: https
      targetPort: 443
      protocol: TCP
    - port: 22
      name: ssh
      targetPort: 22
      protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: gitlab
```

The static ip for `loadBalancerIP` is something you need to get from your google console. Do note that this will not work for a global reserved IP. You have to get a regional IP in the same region as your cluster.

I would've still preferred SSL termination because that's how all of our other services work and the non-homogeneity is kind of annoying me a bit :(

Comment: You can configure Nginx to use SSL for the proxy connection to your upstream server, but obviously this is really just adding an extra SSL termination to the process rather than eliminating the Nginx one. Can't you use Nginx as the load balancer?

Comment: The nginx instance I am using is the one bundled with gitlab, so it is essentially an nginx instance per pod that is created. To use it as a load balancer i would have to install an nginx controller apart from the ones bundled and then use it to load balance connections over the created pods. If i am not mistaken that is what the nginx-ingress component does. The problem then occurs is that it cannot hybrid L4 and L7 load balancing from the same config. And the problem of non-homogeneity still stays.